# Getting Run Time Error 5 on a recorded Pivot Macros

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Open_Projects_pivots()

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Open_Project_Details", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Open Projects pivots!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Open Projects pivots").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Labels")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("ShortId"), "Count of ShortId", xlCount
    Range("A1:C4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Labels").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields( _
        "Requester Team (string)")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

I am getting run time error 5 on this code and unsure what the error is. This is a recorded macros.
FYI "Open_Project_Details" is a dynamic table in the sheet "Open Project Details"
"Open Projects pivots" is the destination sheet and will always remain and this sheet will have a button click for this macros

Comment: I don't think `"Open_Project_Details"` is a valid argument for `SourceData`.

Comment: Thanks for quip response, could you suggest edit, that was automatically taken by recorded macros. Basically "Open_Project_Details" is a dynamic table in the sheet "Open Project Details" which is the source and destination will always be Open Projects pivots with a button in it

Comment: Hmm. Ok yeah if that is a table (`ListObject`) then it should work. Here I'd split the creation of the `PivotCache` and then the `PivotTable` into two separate steps to debug further.

Comment: Exactly where are you seeing the error?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Open_Project_Details", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Open Projects pivots!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6         This is where the error is highlighted

Comment: Actually the issue got resolved, has to add  single quotes to the table destination argument due to the spaces in the sheet name: "'Open Projects pivots'!R1C1"